# Word for continuous waiting for the next new person who arrived to finish

Tags: single-word-requests

A couple of people are having coffee.  When they are about to finish, another person joins.  Now they have to wait for that person to finish.  When person 3 is about to finish, another joins.  Now they have to all wait for the new person also to finish his/her coffee.

Is there a word for this continuously prolonged process of waiting?

Comment: I wonder why they don't just get up and go about their usual business.

Comment: Good luck finding a single word to describe that.

Comment: It would be a large table! but you might want to describe it as an `infinite` wait, or `increasing`, `ever-expanding` or some other term for generally growing.  You could get creative and pad it out from a single word to being metaphorical and say their day seemed to be `buffering`.  Added this as a comment as I don't think the options are a particularly good fit for the question, but could be used

Comment: Please read [Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity?cb=1).